# How can you pass same parameters to different builds without redundant code in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How can you pass same parameters to different builds without redundant code in Jenkins Pipeline groovy.  I don't want to repeat the parameters.

```
node('master') {
    parallel(
        "stream 1(X)" : {
        stage('X') {
            build 'Job1', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: 'trunk'), string(name: 'freq', value: 'Continuous')]
        }
        },
        "stream 2 (Y)" : {
            stage('Y') {
                build 'Job2', parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: 'trunk'), string(name: 'freq', value: 'Continuous')]
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy : just add a function, say `buildJob`, that will take your job name as a parameter and then set all jobs parameters as you do it now :

```
node('master') {
    parallel(
        "stream 1(X)" : {
        stage('X') {
            buildJob("Job1")
        }
        },
        "stream 2 (Y)" : {
            stage('Y') {
                buildJob("Job2")
            }
        }
    )
}

def buildJob(jobName) {
    build name: jobName, parameters: [string(name: 'branch', value: 'trunk'), string(name: 'freq', value: 'Continuous')]
}
```