# Pass (same) parameters to multiple build jobs in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have multiple jobs, 'primary', 'secondary' and 'backup' - All need to have the same parameters (release versions i.e '1.5.1') - There at around 15 of them.

```
parameters{
    string(name: 'service1', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Verison' )
    string(name: 'service2', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Verison' )
    string(name: 'service3', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Verison' )
}
```

My pipeline is like the below, how can I use the same above paramaters for all 3 build jobs without having to specify the parameters three times?

```
//This will kick of the three pipeline scripts required to do a release in PROD 
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages
   {
      stage('Invoke pipeline primary') {
         steps {
            build job: 'primary'
         }
      }
      stage('Invoke pipeline secondary') {
         steps {
            build job: 'secondary'
         }
      }
      stage('backup') {
         steps {
            build job: 'backup'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509430/how-can-you-pass-same-parameters-to-different-builds-without-redundant-code-in-j), but this seems to use groovy syntax and i'm not sure if this can also be used in a declarative pipline like the above?

When I tried it, I get the below:

```
Running on Jenkins in PipelineTest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Invoke pipeline primary)
[Pipeline] build
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: No item named null found
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I run this primary pipeline by itself, it runs as expected.

Thanks!

Edit: Tried the answer provided by @hakamairi but get the below, I'm not great at DSL but tried a few different variations and none worked / all had similar types of errors around expecting a ParamValue.

```
//This will kick of the three pipeline scripts required to do a release in PROD 
pipeline {
   agent any

   parameters{
       string(name: 'service1', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Version' )
       string(name: 'service2', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Version' )
  }

   stages
   {
      stage('Invoke pipeline PrimaryRelease') {
         steps {
             build job: 'PythonBuildTest', parameters: params
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an
>   implementation of interface java.util.List    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:503)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:402)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:361)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:284)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:201)
>     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:208)
>     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor956.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
>   Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate
>   {job=PythonBuildTest, parameters={service1=NA,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the parameters on the pipeline level and just pass the parameters in `build` calls.

```
//This will kick of the three pipeline scripts required to do a release in PROD 
pipeline {
   agent any
    parameters{
        string(name: 'service1', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Verison' )
        string(name: 'service2', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Verison' )
        string(name: 'service3', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Verison' )
    }
   stages
   {
      stage('Invoke pipeline primary') {
         steps {
            build job: 'primary', parameters: ([] + params)
         }
      }
      stage('Invoke pipeline secondary') {
         steps {
            build job: 'secondary', parameters: ([] + params)
         }
      }
      stage('backup') {
         steps {
            build job: 'backup', parameters: ([] + params)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and got this, maybe the parameters need to be a 'list'? 
  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List/.......Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {job=PythonBuildTest, parameters={pcat_sync=NA

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not liking the { params }: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep.setParameters() expects java.util.List<hudson.model.ParameterValue> but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2

Comment: what about now?

Comment: Still no go - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterValue....... Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {job=PythonBuildTest, parameters=[{param1=NA, param2=NA,

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use scripted approach and something like the below works:

```
    def all_params = [
            string(name: 'service1', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Version' ),
            string(name: 'service2', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Version' ),
            string(name: 'service3', defaultValue: 'NA', description: 'Version' ),
        ]
    properties([parameters(all_params)])
```

It should be possible to wrap the above code in a `script` block and use it in a declarative pipeline as well.