# Jenkinsfile Build Job parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkinsfile, I have around 10 jobs and to each Job I am passing parameters as below

```
stage('Test1 )
steps {
  script {
      echo 'Starting "test1"'
      build job: './test1
parameters: [
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'INSTANCE_NAME', value: params.INSTANCE_NAME ],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'WORKSPACE', value: params.WORKSPACE ],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'APP_NAME', value: 'test' ],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: params.GIT_BRANCH ],
] } }
stage('Test2 )
steps {
  script {
      echo 'Starting "test2"'
      build job: './test2' ,
parameters: [
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'INSTANCE_NAME', value: params.INSTANCE_NAME ],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'WORKSPACE', value: params.WORKSPACE ],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'APP_NAME', value: 'test' ],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: params.GIT_BRANCH ],
] } }
```

Is there a way I can define this section outside and use it to pass to the jobs

I am trying the same query @ [Pass (same) parameters to multiple build jobs in a Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144150/pass-same-parameters-to-multiple-build-jobs-in-a-jenkins-pipeline)

Thank you

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Are these 10 jobs downstream jobs that you are building from your Jenkinsfile with the given parameters? What do you mean by defining this section outside?

Comment: Yes, I have these parameters common for all 10 jobs. Defining outside, I meant to use a function to have these parameters and call the function in each build job section. But some how its not working.
I have edited my post with more details

Answer (score 1):

We could pass a map with parameters to build job

```
def jobParameters = [:]
jobParameters['INSTANCE_NAME'] = params.INSTANCE_NAME
jobParameters['WORKSPACE'] = params.WORKSPACE
def paramsObjects = []
jobParameters.each {
  key, value ->
    paramsObjects.push([$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: key, value: value])
}
```

paramsObjects would look like this:

```
[
    [$class:StringParameterValue, name:param1, value:value1],
    [$class:StringParameterValue, name:param2, value:value2]
]
```

The stage config will look like this:

```
     stages {
        stage('Test1')
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'Starting "test1"'
                build job: './test1'
                parameters:
                paramsObjects
            }
        }
        stage('Test2')
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'Starting "test2"'
                build job: './test2',
                        parameters: paramsObjects
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. 
I am getting an error as  
Not a valid section definition: "def parameters = [:]". Some extra configuration is required

Comment: @NiceThomas Most likely this is because `parameters` is a reserved keyword. Try renaming it to something else like `def myJobParameters = [:]`.

Comment: @DibakarAditya you are right. I will update the answer